# TestCafe Browserstack attempts connection to url every 80s or so infinitely without failing

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browserstack

I have an issue whereby our TestCafe tests occasionally run infinitely within BrowserStack.  They eventually fail when the build server hits its 1 hour timeout and ends the build.

```
net::ERR_FAILED

1623775255394:SEVERE:http://172.17.0.2:38363/browser/heartbeat/wxxxxQ - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (No data received from server or forwarder)
1623775255394:SEVERE:http://172.17.0.2:38363/browser/heartbeat/wxxxxQ  - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (No data received from server or forwarder)
1623775255394:SEVERE:http://172.17.0.2:38363/browser/heartbeat/wxxxxQ  - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Forwarding failure)
1623775255394:SEVERE:http://172.17.0.2:38363/browser/heartbeat/wxxxxQ  - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Forwarding failure)
1623775255394:SEVERE:http://172.17.0.2:38363/browser/heartbeat/wxxxxQ  - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Forwarding failure)
1623775255394:SEVERE:http://172.17.0.2:38363/browser/heartbeat/wxxxxQ  - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Forwarding failure)
1623775255394:SEVERE:http://172.17.0.2:38363/browser/heartbeat/wxxxxQ  - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Forwarding failure)
1623775255394:SEVERE:http://172.17.0.2:38363/browser/heartbeat/wxxxxQ  - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Forwarding failure)
1623775255394:SEVERE:http://172.17.0.2:38363/browser/heartbeat/wxxxxQ  - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Forwarding failure)
1623775255394:SEVERE:http://172.17.0.2:38363/browser/heartbeat/wxxxxQ  - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Forwarding failure)
1623775255394:SEVERE:http://172.17.0.2:38363/browser/heartbeat/wxxxxQ  - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Forwarding failure)
1623775255394:SEVERE:http://172.17.0.2:38363/browser/heartbeat/wxxxxQ  - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Forwarding failure)
```

These heartbeat messages appear to be around every 80 seconds.  Is there a way to fail the build quickly based on the above errors being received - am I missing some config or something?

Comment: The strange heartbeat behavior is a consequence of the issue. It's necessary to investigate the cause of the issue. Could you please share an example where I can reproduce the issue?